# how to count the non value and non formula cells?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I'm trying this formula to count the blank cells, and I get "NEW" as if there are none-blank - regardless if there is data in the first cell or not.

How can I fix this?

`=IF(AND(ARRAYFORMULA(ISBLANK(AB8:AB9)+ISNA(AB8:AB9))), "SAME", "NEW")`

[image]

[image]

Comment: That formula doesn't look like it "counts" the blank cells.  It looks like it's designed to tell you if there are any duplicates in a range.  What is the real goal?

Comment: I want to tell if there are only blank cells (return "same") or not (return "new")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An empty string (“”) can be a result of a formula while apostrophe is often used by many people during data entry.

https://productivityspot.com/count-non-blank-cells-google-sheets/

Comment: Is this part of the question, or is this the answer you found. If this is an answer, please provide the formula that worked for your case and a screenshot if possible so more people can benefit from it.

Answer (score 0):

```
=IF(COUNTA(AB8:AB9),"NEW","SAME")
```

Seems that you should just count the values and if it's 0 then it should display "SAME"